# StatusBar color in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar, expo, create-react-native-app

How can I change background color of [`StatusBar`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html) component from `react-native`, without editing Android specific files?

Docs [says](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#backgroundcolor), that I can use [`backgroundColor`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#backgroundcolor) property. But it fails. `barStyle` property, `setBarStyle` && `setBackgroundColor` static methods don`t work properly too.

Only `hidden` property works.

I`m using [`create-react-native-app`](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app), built with [Expo](https://expo.io/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Expo App, you need to edit `app.json` in your project root directory like this:

```
{
    "expo": {
        "sdkVersion": "16.0.0",
        "androidStatusBar": {
            "barStyle": "dark-content",
            "backgroundColor": "#0A48A5"
        }
    }
}
```

See Expo documentation:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v16.0.0/guides/configuration.html

Comment: It helps, but only in combination with  `<StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#1976D2"/>`. Thank you!

Comment: @Tehreem Did you restart expo development? I add this setting above and it only takes effect after I "yarn start" my app again in VS Code

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
<StatusBar
 backgroundColor="blue"
 barStyle="light-content"
/>
```

You can see the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#statusbar).

Answer (score 4):

add **color.xml** in *..android/app/src/main/res/values* and pate following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--   color for the app bar and other primary UI elements -->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>

    <!--   a darker variant of the primary color, used for
           the status bar (on Android 5.0+) and contextual app bars -->
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#A52D53</color>

    <!--   a secondary color for controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

copy and pate following code in *..android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml*

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>    
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';


const bar = ()=>{
  return( <StatusBar backgroundColor="insert your color here"/> );
};
```