# Why Status Bar Color Not Changing?

Tags: react-native

I have this code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <StatusBar
           backgroundColor="blue"
           barStyle="light-content"
         />
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and I run it under EXPO apps on Android 6 - MiUI 8.5. My question is, why status bar still in white. not blue? and nothing is changed. I only got blank white screen (because status bar text in MiUI is also white).

Comment: can you try using "#00F" instead of "blue".

Comment: @SagarKhatri `backgroundColor="#FFB515"` also not changing anything, bro

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917663/statusbar-color-in-react-native/43920029#43920029

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StatusBar color in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917663/statusbar-color-in-react-native)

Comment: @AnsalAli : still failed. I added androidStatusBar in app.json but still same result.

Answer (score 1):

I closed the EXPO app and start it once again. and it works. I think the problem is with the EXPO app.